# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot enter the graphical interface after booting

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

The ubuntu 18.04 desktop version will enter the following interface after restarting:

[image]

[image]

If I want to enter the graphical interface after booting, what method should I take to solve the above problem。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That screen means your machine failed to boot.
See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting for steps to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tilman's answer, a few things can be noted:

- The machine have two drives, but only (hd0) has any partitions, and they're all flagged as MS-DOS type.
- (hd1) does not have any partitions according to GRUB.

This points to that the drive with the Linux installation is either damaged or not recognized by the system, so that it does not manage to boot from it.

Realistically, at this stage, you should probably get hold of someone more familiar with Linux, given the question you ask.

Comment: Thank You very much.